# combine Freeway drive and custom Location in Xcode userLocation simulation

Tags: xcode

how can i simulation a user movement on ios with a custom location? 
-if i choose custom location the map shows a static user
-if i choose freeway drive, the map shows what i want but in San fransicso, what i want is a custom location with Freeway drive

i created a gpx file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<gpx>
   <wpt lat="39.332602" lon="-77.743307"/>
</gpx>
```

I added it in Product-> Scheme-> edit Scheme-> Run-> Options-> Default location

and i enabled 'Allow user Location'

any other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Solved !!!!!

using this tutorial
http://www.cardinalsolutions.com/cardinal/blog/mobile/2013/02/testing_a_location-a.html